# testng eclipse plugin shows only last test class result when run from factory annotation

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, automation, testng

I have a test class whose instances are created from `@Factory` annotation with different parameters. When i run them in eclipse the testNG plugin or window where it shows the output/results shows results for only last test class run. where are other test results from other test class instance runs?
My testng.xml :

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="All Tests Suite">
    <test name="factory test" group-by-instances="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="unitTest.TestNGTestCases.FactoryTest"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

My Factory annotated class:

```
package unitTest.TestNGTestCases;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.testng.annotations.Factory;

public class FactoryTest {  
    @Factory
    public Object[] factory2()
    {
        System.out.println("running factory2");
        List<TestNGTest2> list=new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 6; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add(new TestNGTest2(String.valueOf(i)));
        }
        return list.toArray(new Object[list.size()]);
    } 
}
```

My test class:

```
package unitTest.TestNGTestCases;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNGTest2 {
    private String str;
    public TestNGTest2(String s)
    {
        this.str=s;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void bf()
    {
        System.out.println("running before class "+this.str);
    }
    @Test(priority=1,groups="test1")
    public void t1()
    {
        System.out.println("Running 1"+str);
    }
    @Test(priority=2,groups="test2")
    public void t2()
    {
        System.out.println("Running 2"+str);
    }
    @Test(priority=3,groups="test3")
    public void t3()
    {
        System.out.println("Running 3"+str);
    }
    @Test(priority=4,groups="test4")
    public void t4()
    {
        System.out.println("Running 4"+str);
    }
}
```

I also want that my test class instances to run sequentially as in the order they have been added in list of factory.
What could be done about this?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I've found out the solution, we need to override toString() method and pass every time a new test name. Then we get to see all the results. Something like below :

```
@Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.testName;
    }
```

where testName is a string which is accepted as one of the parameters of the constructor of your factory test class.